# Select range without filtered cells

Tags: excel, select, range, filtering

I have a table with several rows of data. I want to filter some rows and maintain only those which are in compliance with some particular specifics. To do it I can set some filters on the columns.

My problem is that I want to calculate the average/sum/etc.. of the value on some columns, but just considering the rows resulting after applying those filters.

If I select the range with the short-cut 'Shift + Ctrl + arrow key', I'm selecting all the cells in the range, including those filtered.

Do you know how can I work it out?

Thanks

Comment: How if you do ctrl click to your filter cell ?

Comment: It's a solution I would exclude because of the number of cell I have to manually select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AVERAGE()`,`COUNT()`,`COUNTA()`,`MAX()` ,`MIN()`, `PRODUCT()`, `STDEV()`,`STDEVP()` ,`SUM()`,`VAR()`,`VARP()` 
 and alike function will always calculate all Cells in your range, weather Filtered, or Hidden or Neither.

To do what you are looking to do you should use the `SUBTOTAL` Function in Excel.

A Few notes on this Function though:

1. The `SUBTOTAL()` Function will ALWAYS Ignore Filtered Values
2. The `SUBTOTAL()` Function provides 2 Forms of calculation for each of the states Functions, One in which Includes Hidden Rows, And one that Does Not.

***EXAMPLE: ***

If in B1:B10 You have the Values 100-1000, Each Row incrementing 100.

With All Data Visable, Nothing Hidden AND NOTHING Filtered All Functions return the same values:

[image: SetUp]

Now If you **HIDE** A couple rows by highlighting the rows, Right clicking on the Row header and selecting `HIDE` from the Context menu the results will change.

[image: hide3-6]

Notice While `SUBTOTAL(9,B1:B10)` Includes the hidden rows, as does the Normal `Sum()`. `SUBTOTAL(109,B1:B10)` Ignores any Rows that are not Visible.

But when you `Un-hide` the Rows and instead Filter the rows the results again Change:

[image: Filtered]

So, In recap the basic Excel Function  `AVERAGE()`,`COUNT()`,`COUNTA()`,`MAX()` ,`MIN()`, `PRODUCT()`, `STDEV()`,`STDEVP()` ,`SUM()`,`VAR()`,`VARP()` Work on All Data.

If you use `Subtotal()` Function, Function_num's 101-111 Will calculate only ***visible*** rows.

While `Subtotal()` Function, Function_num's 1-11 will calculate all ***NON-HIDDEN*** Rows.

Also, If you are ONLY filtering the data so that you can do the calculations you have other function that will except criteria withing the function.

- `Sumif()` AND `SUMIFS()`
- `COUNTIF()` AND `COUNTIFS()`
- `AVERAGEIF()` AND `AVERAGEIFS()`

Hope this is understandable, and helps you out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are functions like [DAverage](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/daverage.php) and [Dsum](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dsum.php) that allow you to do calculations over a range and specify certain criteria.